# Start a jar with an other jar, and cmd argument

Tags: java, jar, path, exec

I hava a jar with a main file like this:

```
public class StartMesekocka3D {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -Djava.library.path=\"bin\" -jar \"Mesekocka3D.jar\"");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StartMesekocka3D.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to start an other jar with a djava argument. If i double click on the jar (they are in the same folder of course), nothing happens, if i type **java -jar Startmesekocka3D.jar** it's starts the other jar, and works perfect. What should be the problem with double clicking?

Comment: What did you do to make the `StartMesekocka3D` executable ?

Comment: Build it in netbeans, so i get a jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for creating an executable jar which can be started by dbl clicking, you need to define Main Class entry in manifest.mf and then jar it with the new manifest.mf

Comment: this is in the mf file:


Manifest-Version: 1.0

Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2

Created-By: 1.6.0_25-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Class-Path: 

X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Main-Class: startmesekocka3d.StartMesekocka3D

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that double clicking will launch `StartMesekocka3D`.
You have two solutions :

- You can create a batch/shell file (easy solution).
- You can follow [this tutorial](http://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html) to create an executable `jar`. If you are using **Netbeans**, here [is tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html).

Comment: wow, i always thougth if i build it with netbeans it creats an executable jar :O